# $\int_0^{1398\pi} ({\sin^2x})^{\cos^2x}dx=?$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$\int_0^{1398\pi} ({\sin^2x})^{\cos^2x}dx=?$$
$f(x)=({\sin^2x})^{\cos^2x}$ is periodic with period equal to $\pi$,therefore we need to compute the integral in one period.
The original question was:
$$\int_0^{1398\pi} ({\sin^2x})^{\cos^2x}+({\cos^2x})^{\sin^2x}dx=?$$Proposed by Jalil Hajimir to Romanian Math Magazine

Comment: Are you confident there is an exact closed-form solution?

Comment: The integral on $[0,\Pi/2]$ is within `[0.93379891329041 +/- 4.42e-15]`. It does not seem to have a closed from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Comment*.

It's a bit more pleasant to use e.g. $\displaystyle ~\int\limits_0^1 \frac{x^{1-x}+(1-x)^x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}dx~$ than $\displaystyle ~\int\limits_0^{\pi} ((\sin^2 x)^{\cos^2 x} + (\cos^2 x)^{\sin^2 x}) dx~$ .

*I don't know a closed form for that, and it's also very unlikely that exists one here.*

---

*Note:*

If we define $~p_n(x)~$ as a polynomial of degree $n$ , we get:

$$\int\limits_0^1 \frac{x^{1-x}+(1-x)^x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}dx = 2\sqrt{2}
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{p_{2k}(\ln 2)}{2^{2k}(2k+1)!}$$

$p_0(x)=1$

$p_2(x)=x^2+2x-1$

$p_4(x)=x^4+4x^3-6x^2+60x+65$

$p_6(x)=x^6+6x^5-15x^4+300x^3+975x^2+3750x+6687$

$p_8(x)=$

$=x^8+8x^7-28x^6+840x^5+4550x^4+35000x^3+187236x^2+769272x+1305089$

...

Comment: [Comments containing MathJax are not being displayed fully](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30982).

Comment: @Calum Gilhooley : Thanks for the info! I haven't changed my type or writing, but the last time (= a few days ago), everything was displayed. I've read the texts but I still don't understand how to get rid of this problem. I will see ...